# Php java bridge Error : the procedure entry point php set error handling could not be located in dynamic link library C:\xampp\php\ext\php_java.dll

Tags: php, apache, php-java-bridge

Integrating PHP java bridge, facing some issue while restarting Apache server as showing error:

> *The procedure entry point php set error handling could not be located in dynamic link library **C:\xampp\php\ext\php_java.dll***

I made the changes outlined below in my `php.ini` file and copied ***`JavaBridge.jar`*** and ***`php_java.dll`*** in ***`C:\xampp\php\ext`***.

```
extension=php_java.dll

[java]
java.java_home = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin"
java.java = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaw.exe"
java.class.path = "C:\xampp\php\ext\JavaBridge.jar"
java.library.path = "C:\xampp\php\ext"
java.log_level =2
```

Comment: Do your PHP and java extension versions match? http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/installation.php says `Do not search for a PHP extension, java.so or php_java.dll. These extensions are obsolete.` so I would say they don't :-)

Comment: @Capsule it doesn't work. I have x86 bit xampp and I uninstalled 64 bit java and installed x86. but it shows same error.

Comment: Well, next time I won't even bother providing a link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to your question:

First of all, the javabridge communication is not handled anymore by a php extension *(I mean the php_java.dll or java.so)*.

So you simply don't need it, you can completly remove the "extension=php_java.dll" as this has been replaced by a pure php implementation known as the `Java.inc` client *(or alternatively the `soluble-japha` [client](http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/))*.

I believe you use a very old documentation... So don't spend too much time in this direction because you'll probably won't have support.

But if you want to work with the javabridge, just remember you'll have to install both:

- **a *Java* server** that will expose the Java virtual machine on a network port *(standalone or deployed on Tomcat)*
- **a PHP client library** on the PHP side that will establish communication with the server (Java.inc or soluble-japha)

I suggest you to read the docs on the official [php-java-bridge website](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) to get some insights about installation *(or alternatively some docs for the [unofficial soluble-japha](http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/) project, they work pretty much the same way).*

And first ensure, the php-java-bridge server is sucessfully running. The php-java-bridge files can be downloaded either:

- Option 1: The war file (tomcat only) is [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/php-java-bridge_7.1.3/)
- Option 2: Individual files for cli/standalone server are [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/php-java-bridge_7.1.3/exploded/)

Once it works, try to connect from PHP.

You'll probably face a lot of problems at first run, but from there it will be easier to answer your questions.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you . Java Bridge connection established but facing problems like some security .jar files are missing in tomcat. How to connect tomcat with external java as that .jar files are present there.

Comment: Oups haven't seen the comment. Hope you get through the problem. But better to create a separate issue.